# Creating multiple buttons using input field in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to ask how can I multiple the buttons by using the input field? Like for example, I typed 100 in the input field and then the buttons will become 100. Please bear in mind that I'm new in Unity. Thank you!

Comment: Is your question about code written using the C# programming language, or the Unityscript scripting language that was deprecated a few years ago? Hint: you've tagged both, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Did you try something so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now and I'm pretty sure this is not the language you will be using

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define *what* button you want to instantiate, on the UI Canvas or a 3D world button.

```
public class TestingScript : MonoBehaviour{

// the button to create
public GameObject button;

}
```

You need to create a prefab or assign an existing button in the world for the script to use as a template when creating them. Next you need to create the input field itself and assign the reference to it through code or in the inspector view, here I am going to have it assigned in the inspector.

```
// assigned in inspector view
public TMP_InputField inputField;
```

It should look like this in the component view

[image: Components]

Now *where* you call the function is your choosing, I am doing it through a unity button on which I have the script attached

[image: Button]

The method here would look something like this

```
public void CreateButtons()
{
    // here we assume the input is always an integer, otherwise you would create a try catch clause
    int amount = int.Parse(inputField.text);

    // using world 0 position here, you would need to define where you want them yourself
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        // the loop will execute the amount of times read from input field
        Instantiate(button, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        pos.x += 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Note I am using TextMeshPro elements here but the standard unity ones would work too.